# Error on launch attempt of Visual dBASE 5.5 in Win 7 (Home & Pro)

Tags: windows-7

I've run the program on multiple OS's and in fact it ran on this Toshiba Laptop for 3 years under Vista then Windows 7 Home Premium. Last time I tried to run it the following error comes up after the Borland splash screen

> Invalid driver name or insufficient system resources: winspool

I even upgraded to Windows 7 Pro hoping it might correct the problem but I'm still stuck.

Answer (score 1):

Check your printers.  I've seen this error before when someone had an installed printer that was offline or non-existent.